# Scroll covering the div element in HTML

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

When I press the button (*+ Add card*) the div element is created, like a card. At the same time I have scroll, covering the card. Like in the image below. I don't want this. How can I avoid this? 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/62QY8/54/)
[image]

```
/*Style of a inbox list*/
#inboxList {
    width: 275px; height: 700px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-top: 0.4%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px #828282;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Just increase the width? Or am I missing something?

Comment: When you don't want the scrollbar set `overflow: auto` not scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/62QY8/55/ ... I don't get the people who downvote these questions. There is code a demo and even an image. It's not too clear what the actual question is, but i think some people act a bit harsh -

Comment: @NicoO Downvote was because OP obviously doesn't show any effort to resolve his issue, like, e.g, trying to understand simple code he is using. Looks fair to me. "How can i remove scrollbar?" "Why on earth then are you using `overflow: scroll;`??? Etc... And ya question is quite unclear, we don't know exactly what is expecting OP if content is tallest than container

Comment: I understand your point @A.Wolff, it is just that OP seems to be pretty new to the material. When we look at `This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)` I come to the conclusion, "shows research effort" - check,  "it is useful and clear" - no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting fixed height, use `min-height` instead, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/57/

And of course, remove: `overflow: scroll;`

**UPDATE:**

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h469S/)

```
$('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
        var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
        cnt++;
        $newDiv.prop("id", "div" + cnt);
        var $userAddedCard = $('#userAddedCard');
        $userAddedCard.append($newDiv);
        var testWidth = $userAddedCard.innerWidth() - $userAddedCard[0].scrollWidth;
        if (testWidth) {
            $userAddedCard.find('.sortable-div').width(260 + testWidth);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear sorry. I still want the scroll. At the same time if I add a lot of cards, at some point the cards will reach the bottom . Then I'm suppose to use "overflow: auto;" in CSS. And still the scroll will cover the card. Is it possible to make the card shrink when scroll occurs? Do you understand me?

Comment: You can detect the horizontal scrollbar and then set relevant width, see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily only change the css display Property like

```
#inboxList {
    /* other styles */
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Or just remove overflow:scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of "#inboxList" to 350px