# Problems with remove timestamps in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I double click the card the dialog pops up, and it is then possible to create comments. So far so good. When creating the comments it is possible to delete it.

The issue is, that the timestamps can't be removed. The way I'm trying to remove the timestamps is by this line: `$('.labelStyle').remove();` 
I want to be able to remove the timestamps, like the others elements but how?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/145/)

JQuery: "click" handler

```
$('#divComments').on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
        var uniqueval = $(this).attr("for")
        var NameOfDataValue = $('label[for=' + uniqueval + ']').text();
        $('img[for=' + uniqueval + ']').remove();
        $('label[for=' + uniqueval + ']').remove();
        $('p[for=' + uniqueval + ']').remove();
        $('.labelStyle').remove();
        var arr = $('#divComments').data('comments');
        var theIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].commentString== NameOfDataValue) {
                theIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (theIndex == -1) {
            alert("Error");
        }
        else {
            $('#divComments').data("comments").splice(theIndex, 1);
        }

    });
```

JQuery: Add comment function

```
function addComment(commentString) {

        var container = $('#divComments');
        var inputs = container.find('label');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;
        var data1 = {            
            commentString: commentString
        };

        var div = $('<div />', { class: 'CommentStyle' });

        $('<label />', {
            id: 'comment' + id,
            for: 'comment' + id,
            text: commentString
        }).on('change', function () {            
            data1.commentString = $(this).text();
        }).appendTo(div);      

        $('<br/>').appendTo(div);

        var $Image = $('<img />',
            {
                "src": "/Pages/Images/alert.png",
                "class": "CommentImage",
                "for": "comment" + id
            }).appendTo(container);

        var d = new Date();
        var $fulaDate = $('<div>' + d.getDate()
            + "-" + monthNames[d.getMonth()]
            + "-" + d.getFullYear()
            + "//" + d.getHours()
            + ":" + d.getMinutes()
            + '</div>').addClass('labelStyle').append(' ~').appendTo(div);

        var $edit = $('<p />', {
            class: 'edit',
            for: 'comment' + id,
            text: 'Edit'
        }).append(' ~').appendTo(div);

        var $delete = $('<p />', {
            class: 'delete',
            for: 'comment' + id,
            text: 'Delete'
        }).appendTo(div);        

        div.appendTo(container).focus();

        container.data('comments').push(data1);

    }
```

Comment: 145 jsFiddle edits :O That is a first XD

Comment: @Andrei: I was wondering if I had seen that before, and here it is. It is the same fiddle going on for months! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687867/scroll-covering-the-div-element-in-html

Comment: What do je mean with that? I didn't get you point :)

Comment: Why do you want to remove each element, one by one ? If you remove the parent, every other elements will be destroyed also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(this).parent().find('.labelStyle').remove();
```

This will select the parent of the clicked button (`.CommentStyle`) then find the `.labelStyle` and remove it.

Comment: Hmm this is not working. The timestamp dose not removed.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/146/ you can see it here. If the answer helped you, don't forget to accept it.